# Cannot set custom taxonomies when creating post

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I'm migrating some posts from another source to WordPress, specifically to a theme/plugin called Madara, which has some specific taxonomies. I'm using `wp_insert_post()` to create the post, everything works fine until I try to set the taxonomies, I tried to set the taxonomies directly via the `tax_input` array on the `wp_insert_post()`, even with a `post_auhtor` defined and the `wp_set_current_user()` set, it didn't work.

I also tried with the `wp_set_object_terms()` after creating the post, but I've getting `Invalid taxonomy` error.

this is a sample screenshot taken from the "Quick Edit" request on admin panel, basically the same way I'm defining in on `wp_insert_post()`

[image]

Important: This is not a regular wordpress plugin, it is a cron job that's just using WordPress functions.

Wordpress files being included in the cron code:

```
require_once "../../../wp-load.php";
require_once "../../../wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php";
require_once "../../../wp-admin/includes/file.php";
require_once "../../../wp-admin/includes/image.php";
require_once "../../../wp-admin/includes/media.php";
```

How can I add those taxonomies?

Comment: Can you confirm that the cron job script is loading what is required to register the custom taxonomy and connect it to the core **post** post type? When you say *cron job* do you mean **WP\_Cron** or command line `cron`? Please note [StackOverflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for asking good questions. They discourage use of images to present code and output from debugging, warnings or errors. Text should be used.

Comment: A command line cron job, just like php code.php....
I'll update the question with the loaded Wordpress files that I'm using in the cron

Comment: I do not see the call to the [register_taxonomy()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/) function anywhere. I'm guessing this function call is buried in the code for the Madara theme. How do you know this cron command line script is loading the Madara theme?

Comment: The theme installs some taxonomies before hand, it already exists on the DB.
I'm having a hard time trying to understand why I have to register it if it already is on db, I thought this taxonomy creation was just like categories.

Comment: Do i have to call register_taxonomy before creating it? even if it already exists?

Comment: Yes, you have to call `register_taxonomy()`. The `taxonomy` column of the `wp_term_taxonomy` database table shows taxonomies that have been registered. But, the presence of a custom taxonomy in this table does not mean the taxonomy is active. When a browser makes a request to the server, WordPress calls `register_taxonomy()` to activate that taxonomy for its associated post types for that browser connection. So, it looks like WordPress is registering the taxonomy at each connection. You can test this by disabling the call to `register_taxonomy()` for one of your registered custom taxonomies.